# xcode: Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error "getInt", referenced from:

Tags: c#, xcode

I have installed cs50.h on Xcode, as intructed on https://manual.cs50.net/CS50_Library#Mac_OS_2. 
Search path on build in project for header has been set by me to /usr/local/include and library to use/local/lib (both on project and target).

*#include cs50.h* compiles, but the build fails with **Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error "getInt()", referenced from:**
I am very new to xcode, a detailed solution will be appreciated.

OS X10.8
xCode 4.4

Comment: this is c#? and please properly format your error so we can see after **referenced from:**